# Add a servlet to my web.xml directly from pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-3

I want to add a servlet to my web.xml so when an specific URL is browsed, instead of reading the self-generated helloworld.jsp the browser is redirected to my servlet.

I know I can do this by modifying web.xml, but I don't think this is a normal procedure if when executing a mvn clean the web.xml is wipped out.

I want instead that my pom.xml could fill my web.xml with the servlet tags, but I haven't found a way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Answering to myself: web.xml is created only once and not at package time as I had in mind. Hence, the only way to custom the package is effectively modifying web.xml, which will be left untouched no matter the maven commmand run.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not the case try to your project to, at least, java 6

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.6</source>
    <target>1.6</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and then modify the xsd definition in your web.xml to go to 3.0

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0">
```

Now you can use the WebServlet annotation on each servlet and there is no need to define them in the web descriptor.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/the/url/to/servlet")
```